# How to manage the cursor shape for a custom QWidget Container in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

**How to set a custom cursor for a custom QWidget container?**

**Extended context:**

In the process of implementing a custom `QWidget` container:

The widget `[Child]` of any arbitrary `QWidget` class is embedded in an other `[Parent]` which is our custom container:

> ```
> [Parent] of type CustomContainer
>    |
>    |---> [Child] An arbitrary non-custom QWidget.
> ```

It is required to set a special mouse cursor when pointing to some zones of the `CustomContainer`, but the `Child` need to keep it normal cursor.

**Unsuccessful tries:**

In principle, it could be like:

```
void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (specialRect->contains(ev->pos())) setCursor(Qt::SizeVerCursor);
    else setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
}
```

Unfortunately, the `mouseMoveEvent` is only received when the cursor is directly on the `[Parent]` so the cursor is not restored to its original shape for the `[Child]`. The same rule apply to `enterEvent` and `leaveEvent`.

An alternative would be to set an event filter, this is not a problem for an application, but a QWidget class should IMO not register event filters which could carry side effects, slowing the application, etc.

Comment: Event filters are made exactly for this.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: installing the event filter on the customContainer is not capturing the childs events. How could I access the QApplication object to setup a global filter? Or what is the way?

Comment: Isn't the problem simply that `child` doesn't have a set cursor of its own and will, therefore, inherit the parent's cursor?  Try doing `child->setCursor(child->cursor())` *before* setting the container's cursor to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Your solution seem to works. thanks.
G.M.: The point is to not modify anything of the child, as this could have side-effect: what happens if any further code change the child of parent? or insert new childs? or the child expect a specific cursor set in the constructor?.

Comment: @AdrianMaire -- Ok, understood.  On the other hand... in situations such as that I often find it very useful to insert an extra widget between the container and child and have the container manage the extra widget.  That way you can affect the behaviour of the child without having to modify it directly.  Just FYI.